# Solve $x^3 - x - 1=0$ over $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}_7$

Tags: real-analysis, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, p-adic-number-theory, complete-spaces

Is possible to find a solution to $x^3 - x - 1 \approx 0$ using p-adic numbers? I can state this question as two inequalities.  Find $x = \frac{m}{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$:

- $|x^3 - x - 1 |_\infty < 0.001$
- $|x^3 - x - 1 |_7 < \frac{1}{7^3}$

There are infinitely many such fractions.  So another more general question could be to describe them.  How about, let's limit ourselves to $x = \frac{m}{n}$ with $|m|+|n| < 10^6$.  I would accept a computer solution if there are too many solutions.

We could write the simultaneous inequalities as, solve for $x = \frac{m}{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $|m| + |n| < 10^6$ ("[taxicab norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)" or $L^1$ norm or $\ell_1$ distance even though there's only two coordinates.)

- $|x^3 - x - 1 | < \frac{1}{10^3}$
- $x^3 - x - 1  \equiv 0 \pmod {7^3}$

Comment: $f(x)=x^3-x-1$ is separable modulo $7$ and has only one root $5$ which lifts with Hensel lemma to a unique root in $\Bbb{Q}_7$. ie. $a_1=5, a_{n+1} = a_n-f(a_n)/f'(a_n)\implies f(a_n)\equiv 0\bmod 7^n$. We get $a_2  = 12 \bmod 7^2$ and hence $$|x^3-x-1|_7 \le 7^{-2} \quad \iff \quad x =  \frac{12 s + 7^2 r}{s}, 7\nmid s$$

Comment: Is Hensel lemma applicable to cubic?

Comment: The proof of Hensel lemma takes one line. $f(a_n+b 7^n) = f(a_n)+b7^n f'(a_n) + O(7^{2n}) = f(a_n)+b7^n  f'(a_n)\bmod 7^{n+1}$ with $a_{n+1}=a_n+b7^n, b7^n=-f(a_n)/f'(a_n)$ we get $f(a_{n+1})=0\bmod 7^{n+1}$.

Comment: Since you initially specified the 7-adic norm is _less than_ $7^{-3}$, congruence $\bmod343$ is not enough.  You need congruence $\bmod 2401$.  For instance, $686\equiv0\bmod 343$ but $|686|_7\not<7^{-3}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I arrive at $7193/5430=1.32467...\equiv1384\bmod 2401$.  The base ten representation is close enough to the exact answer (1.32471...) to guarantee $|x^3-x-1|<0.001$, and $1384\bmod2401$ gives $x^3-x-1\equiv0$ exactly.

I will first seek a solution for $|x^3-x-1|<0.001$, using the real-arithmetic norm, via continued fractions.  This in itself does not solve the *simultaneous* equations, but it can be used as a springboard to such a simultaneous solution.

Start with the fact that by substitution we find there is a root $r_0$ between $1$ and $2$ (which is the only real root, actually, as we can infer from the cubic discriminant $27(-1)^2+4(-1)^3>0$).  So render this root as the continued fraction $[1,r_1]=1+(1/r_1)$.  Then

$(1+(1/r_1))^3-(1+(1/r_1))-1=0$

Expanding the binomial power $(1+(1/r_1))^3$, then clearing fractions and collecting terms gives

$r_1^3-2r_1^2-3r_1-1=0$

with its root between $3$ and $4$.  Thus $r_0=[1,3,r_2]$ with $r_1=3+(1/r_2)$.  Thereby

$(1+(1/r_2))^3-2(1+(1/r_2))^2-3(1+(1/r_2))-1=0$

$r_2^3-12r_2^2-7r_2-1=0$

We find $r_2$ lies between $12$ and $13$.

Therefore our root lies between $[1,3,12]=49/37=1.32432...$ and $[1,3,13]=53/40=1.325$.  These bounds lie within $0.001$ of each other, but it turns out that neither bound actually satisfies the condition $|x^3-x-1|<0.001$.  Although the true root itself is within $0.001$ of the bounds, the derivative at the root is greater than $1$ and thus the error in the polynomial value is greater.

There is, however, a subtle way to improve those bounds.  If we go back to the cubic equation for $r_2$ we note that since $r_2$ is clearly greater than $1$ we have

$r_2^3-12r_2^2-7r_2-r_2<r_2^3-12r_2^2-7r_2-1<r_2^3-12r_2^2-7r_2-0$

$r_2(r_2^2-12r_2-8)<r_2^3-12r_2^2-7r_2-1<r_2(r_2^2-12r_2-7)$

Thus the true root $r_2$ lies between the roots of the quadratic equations $r_2^2-12r_2-7=0$ and $r_2^2-12r_2-8=0$, thus between $6+\sqrt{43}$ and $6+\sqrt{44}$.  As $(13/2)^2=42.25$ and $(20/3)^2=44.44444...$ this implies that $r_2$ actually lies between $25/2=[12,2]$ and $38/3=[12,1,2]$.  Thus

$[1,3,12,2]<r_0<[1,3,12,1,2]$

$102/77<r_0<155/117$

These bounds do give $|x^3-x-1|<0.001$, and in particular the fraction $102/77$ is the minimal such fraction in terms of numerator and denominator size.

To bring in the $7-adic$ requirement we must first find the solution in $7$-adics alone.  Modulo $7$ the equation $x^3-x-1=0$ has the unique solution $x\equiv5$, and by Hensel lifting this can be converted to $x\equiv1384\bmod2401$.  The latter, represented in $7$-adics as $...4015$, implements the requirement $|x^3-x-1|_7\le 7^{-4}<7^{-3}$.

We then take the bounds derived from the continued fraction above and form a combined fraction lying between them:

$\dfrac{102a+155b}{77a+117b}$

where $a$ and $b$ are positive whole numbers and the $7$-adics requirement renders

$102a+155b\equiv 1384(77a+117b)\bmod 2401$

$-106466a\equiv161773b\bmod 2401$

$1579a\equiv906b\bmod2401$

$a\equiv 69b\bmod 2401$

So simply render $a=69,b=1$:

$x=\dfrac{102×69+155}{77×69+117}=\color{blue}{\dfrac{7193}{5430}}.$

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fairly generic method, start by using Newton's method to get a solution to arbitrary accuracy in both fields. Let's suppose our approximations are the rational numbers, $x_\infty$ and $x_7$.

Now we can join them into a single solution by a linear combination of both of them, $$x=ax_7 +b x_\infty$$

It's a fun exercise to see that the following two sequences of rational numbers have limits that go to 0 in one field and 1 in the other, for our purposes an easy choice is for $n$ large as you like,

$$a = \frac{1}{1+7^n}$$
$$b = \frac{7^n}{1+7^n}$$

So this means

$$x=\frac{x_7+x_\infty 7^n}{1+7^n}$$

So here as an example, just recklessly picking a bunch of digits arbitrarily $x_\infty = \frac{1324717957244746}{10^{15}}$ and $x_7 = 67770352087443486$ and $n=40$ we have,
$$x = \frac{4217110960882744163328506069361294227335237174373}{3183402880454513992870717569612001000000000000000}$$

This happens to be close up to about $17$ digits in the reals and $20$ digits in the $7$-adics. I didn't count the digits of accuracy for my example beforehand, but this will just be limited by whatever point you stopped your digits of accuracy in the local fields since the $a,b$ sequences can always be chosen arbitrarily close to $0$ and $1$.